# Placing dotnet scaffolded files in Models folder

Tags: .net-core

I successfully executed:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Host=myDbServer;Database=profiles_editor_data;Username=myUsername;Password=mypassword" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL
```

However, this cmd places the classes files in my project's root folder. Is there a way to force it to place all these files in the Models folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation has a section "Target directories and namespaces"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#target-directories-and-namespaces), which explains the option you would use to put the scaffolded files in whatever directory you wish.

You can try the following command:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Host=myDbServer;Database=profiles_editor_data;Username=myUsername;Password=mypassword" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL --output-dir Models
```